# Using 2 differents component on a same route path to show a Popup

Tags: reactjs

I spent hours trying to show up my Popup component when i click to my button .

How can i make sure to show first the "Avaibalities" component and then when i click my "Modal" component using the same Avaibalities route path?

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Avaibalities from './pages/Avaibalities';
import Modal from './pages/Modal';

<BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/Avaibalities" component={Avaibalities} />
              <Route path="/Avaibalities" component={Modal} />
            </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Avaibalities component

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from '../pages/Modal';
class Avaibalities extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showModal: false
  }
  togglePop = () => {
    this.setState({
      showModal: !this.state.showModal
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>    
             <div>
                <button className={'button'}
                >Validate</button>
                <div>
                  {this.state.showModal ? <Modal toggle={this.togglePop} /> : null}
                </div>
              </div>
              <button className={'buttonReset'} onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Avaibalities;
```

Modal component

```
import React from 'react';


class Modal extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.toggle();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="modal">
        <div className="modal_content">
          <span className="close" onClick={this.handleClick}>&times;</span>
          <p>I'm A Pop Up!!!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Modal;
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to specify the route more than once:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/Avaibalities" component={Avaibalities} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The "magic" will happen in your `Avaibalities` component itself.

Typically, a `Modal` component will overlay the content underneath it. If this is how your modal works, you will simply need to have it display alongside your component when it is toggled on:

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      {this.state.showModal && <Modal toggle={this.togglePop} />}
      <div>    
        <div>
          <button className={'button'}>Validate</button>
        </div>
        <button className={'buttonReset'} onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

However, if you for some reason *only* want to show the `Modal` and *don't* want to show the underlying content, you might opt to `return` early from your `render` method:

```
render() {
  if(this.state.showModal) {
    return  <Modal toggle={this.togglePop} />;
  }

  return (
    <div>    
      <div>
        <button className={'button'}>Validate</button>
      </div>
      <button className={'buttonReset'} onClick={this.reset}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: If he’s using your second option why not just create a route for the modal itself?

Comment: Well, mostly because OP asked for "using the same Avaibalities route path"